# Scraping python beatifualsoup: найти элемент по его тегу. К примеру, <dd>

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Как найти элемент если он имеет не стандартные названия типо div, span, a, p и так далие. А свое название типо dd?

```
url = "https://www.grainger.com/search?searchBar=true&searchQuery=SL1-A"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
model =  soup.find("dd", attrs={'class':'list-view__product-detail-value'})
print(model)
print(model.text)
```

Это кусок кода для вытаскивания данного элемента

```
<dd class='list-view__product-detail-value'>Model</dd>
```

Пишет что model не имеет атрибута текст. Я понимаю что это значит но тогда возникает вопрос как вытащить текст из этого блока

Comment: Хм? `dd` вообще-то тоже стандартный, как и `div`, `span`, `a`, `p`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, подойдет вариант с selenium :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
# https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
# скопировать в C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.grainger.com/search?searchBar=true&searchQuery=SL1-A"
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
model = soup.find("dd", attrs={'class':'list-view__product-detail-value'})
print (model)
print (model.text)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Разве обычная конструкция не работает?

```
find_items1 = soup.find('dd', attrs={'class' : 'list_block grid col-xs-24'})
find_items2 = find_items1.find_all('zz')
```

Comment: Пробовал но пото пишет мол у этого элемента нет атрибута text. А его нужно вывести.

Comment: Вы не привели ни код, ни кусок супа для скармливания - без этого вам невозможно помочь т.к. в оригинале конструкция работает.
 `x1 = soup.find('dd')`   `print (x1)` `print (x1.text)`  `>> <dd>Problem is, it isn't shown as full access</dd>`  `>> Problem is, it isn't shown as full access`

Comment: `<dd class="list-view__product-detail-value">Model F</dd>`

Comment: Нужно вычленить отсюда текст `url = "https://www.grainger.com/search?searchBar=true&searchQuery=SL1-A"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
model =  soup.find("dd", attrs={'class':'list-view__product-detail-value'})
print(model)
print(model.text)`

Comment: Все дело в том, что в супе при таком подходе нет элемента 'dd', попробуйте найти его в  `print (soup)` -  эти элементы генерируются скриптами, которые должен выполнять браузер. Из возможных вариантов решения данного вопроса - selenium. Код отдельным комментом скину.